# Error installing MongoDb Compass on Windows

Tags: mongodb, installation, mongodb-compass

I am having trouble installing mongodb compass 1.34.0 on windows 11 and the error shows up saying "Error while validating preferences from: Command Line". Is there a solution to this?

[image: Screenshot of error]

I tried redownloading the application and restarting the laptop, however nothing changed.

Answer (score -1):

I just downloaded latest version of Mongo Compass, and I had the exact same error. My solution was to download de MSI installer instead of the .exe

[image: download msi]